# Laravel Blade Template IF/ELSEIF not yielding content based off user variable

Tags: php, html, laravel, authentication, laravel-4

I have a variable, $permissions, which stores whatever permissions value the user has in the database in the view to be used in my if/elseif statement. For some reason though, they content will not load like I want it to. I have the variable echoed to make sure that it is coming through, and it is. Why are my sections not appearing properly?

```
@define $permissions = Auth::user()->permissions

    @if ($permissions===1)
        @yield('dist1')
    @elseif ($permissions===2)
        @yield('dist2')
    @elseif ($permissions===3)
        @yield('dist3')
    @elseif ($permissions===4)
        @yield('dist4')
    @elseif ($permissions===5)
        @yield('dist5')
    @endif
```

@Define's code in my global.php is:

```
Blade::extend(function($value) {
return preg_replace('/\@define(.+)/', '<?php ${1}; ?>', $value);
});
```

When I echo {{ $permissions }} after logging in as a particular user it WILL echo the correct number. In the table I have the value set for "permissions" as an integer with a default of "0". Of the two users I am trying, one has a value of "2" and the other has a value of "0".

Comment: Are you sure that `$permissions` returns an int? Can you show us it's content?

Comment: I have added info above, thanks for your question. It seems like it returns an int to me.

Comment: have you tried replacing the define with php code? `<?php $permissions = Auth::user()->permissions ?>` Also maybe try just writing everything in php instead of blade to help track down the issue

Comment: "seems like it returns an int" is not very precise. You're using the strict comparison operator. If `$permissions` is a string containing an integer, and not of type integer, it will not hit any of your if statements, so it would be good to know for sure. What does `gettype($permissions)` show you?

Comment: It is a string... hmm... sorry about that. I will try "="

Comment: So , i use @if ($permissions=1), 2, 3, 4, 5 it only shows section 1, as opposed to any other section, even when permission is 3, 4, etc. any ideas?

Comment: Just did == ... works now.. thank u for the tip